# How to replace list items where list is an object attribute?

Tags: python, list, replace

I want to loop through an object's attributes with a given parameter and replace some elements.

Object name is: **DATA**

**DATA** has these attributes :
**name[string], version[string] and apps[list of app objects]**

Apps list includes application objects

An app object in apps list has these attributes : **app.name [string] ; app.ctrl[list]**

In ctrl list each item has 5 value : **[** value0 , [value1a,value1b] , value2, value3, value4 **]**

I want to loop through the object elements and find the correct DATA.apps.ctrl list element target and replace value[1][0] and value[1][1]  :

```
for app in self.DATA.apps:

    if self.SelectedAppID.get() == app.name:

        for control in app.ctrl:

            if control[0] == self.SelectedCtrl.get():

                control[1][0] = valuenew
                control[1][1] = valuenew
```

I find the application and element I want to change. I think I am replacing it but it does not work. The list remains the same...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your `if` statements are even being entered and the values are being set?  You should use a debugger and step through the code

Comment: Yes everything is fine. I have debug on each line..  And reports correct Adam.. I print  control list before replace and after replace , it changes. But on the program scale no changes visible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the data object, you are updating the variables that you create in the loop, those are stored as values, not as references to the main object.

Comment: So I need to find the index to that values to update them .. Loop has many depths . How can i find this index ? If i know the index i won't use the loop and just replace via index...

Comment: for index, control in enumerate(app.ctrl):

Comment: might be end up being something like: data[app.name][index][1][0] = 'new value'